# PHP SimpleXML - can't get a single node value, am I crazy?

Tags: php, simplexml

I simplified my php code to the minimum and still cannot get a simple xml node's value. I re-read the documentation to make sure I wasn't missing some tiny details and I just can't get it to work.

First I load this very basic XML

```
    $xmlStrShipping = simplexml_load_string('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
    <Shipping>
        <Orders>
            <Order>
                <number>Order number</number>
                <details></details>
            </Order>
        </Orders>
    </Shipping>');
```

Then I can't get the *number* and *details* nodes' value, I just keep getting a *SimpleXMLElement Object*:

```
var_dump($xmlStrShipping); // So far, so good
/* Returns:
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
[Orders] => SimpleXMLElement Object
    (
        [Order] => SimpleXMLElement Object
            (
                [number] => Order number
                [details] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                    )

            )

    )

)
*/
```

.

```
var_dump($xmlStrShipping->Orders[0]->Order->number); // Why is this happening?
/* Returns
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => Order number
)
*/
```

.

```
var_dump($xmlStrShipping->Orders[0]->Order->number[0]); // What??
/* Returns
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)
*/
```

Why can't I retrieve *number*?
And why is *details* a *SimpleXMLElement Object* instead of an empty string?

Comment: This method return a SimpleXMLElement object. Please use cast $test = (string) $xmlStrShipping->Orders[0]->Order->number; to get string value

Comment: If you look in the documentation, they are using it exactly like I am and it doesn't return a SimpleXMLElement and they don't have to use a type casting that makes the code look weird: http://php.net/simplexml_load_string

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SimpleXML turns everything into SimpleXMLElement objects. Just cast it to a string (or whatever):

```
(string) $xmlStrShipping->Orders[0]->Order->number;
```

or if you invoke it in a string context it will work as well because SimpleXMLElement has the magic [`__toString()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.tostring.php) method implemented:

```
echo $xmlStrShipping->Orders[0]->Order->number;
```

Comment: Ah, I see, so there is no way to put save that string in another variable as an empty string when it's empty, unless having to add an ugly type casting huh? :(

Comment: I just checked in the comments for type casting after seeing your answer and you're right.. A guy did warn about this issue, my bad for failing to see that one, I only checked the first comment on the docs